# postgresql text search: 2712 index size limit error

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm trying to use postgresql fulltext functionality to add text-search to our application.

Currently, it gives the error

> index row size 4016 exceeds maximum 2712 for index

I got this for a document that was 3880 (english) in char length. Does this mean that postgres fts can't be used for larger documents ? 3880 isn't all that large ? The error appears when I try to update the index, so one solution would be to not use an index at all but wouldn't that affect the search performance ?

I'm new to postgresql in general and am really sure that I must be doing something really wrong.

Comment: You need to show more detail. If you show us the results from running `psql` and executing `\d tablename` (specifying your actual table name, of course), that might be enough. I've used PostgreSQL full text search for legal documents running to hundreds of pages, so there's probably some mistake in how you are using it.

Comment: Hi guys,

I have a similar problem with insert queries which have been running for ages.


`CREATE INDEX idx_fielddata_wr
  ON wr
  USING btree
  (fd COLLATE pg_catalog."default");`

fd is character varying (4000)

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to index a text field for fts, my suggestion is that you should index a tsvector based on the text.  Something like

```
CREATE INDEX my_fts_idx ON my_table(to_tsvector(mytext));
```

A tsvector is much smaller than the full text of the column also.

Comment: for a large field sha1 would be expected to be smaller.  The larger issue though is that sha1 can only give you an equality scan, while a tsvector still gives you full text search capabilities (GiST).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you'll get this error when you try to index a `text` field, remove that index and you'll be fine.